# Tenor API with aiohttp not working python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, discord.py, aiohttp

i'm creating a discord bot with discord.py. Right now im trying to make it so it sends a gif with the Tenor API. I created my API key with the google cloud tool. This is the code

```py
    async def get_gif(self, search):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:  
            key = os.getenv("API_KEY")
            async with session.get("https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q={}&key={}&limit=1".format(search, key)) as resp:   
                
                if resp.status == 200:     #checks if response is correct
                    resp = await resp.json()
                    resp = resp['results'][0]['media'][0]['gif']['url']
                    return resp
                else:
                    return resp.status
    
    @commands.command(name="gif", aliases=["gf"])
    async def gif(self, ctx, args):
        await ctx.send(await self.get_gif(args))
```

I'm constantly getting error 401 and i can't figure out why, I tried with requests and it still didn't work. why am i getting this error? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there might be other problems in your code, I didn't check carefully but I think the main issue comes from the url you're using:

```
"https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q={}&key={}&limit=1"
```

I was using the old documentation from tenor where they use the "v1" api in the url but it is now "v2". This is updated in the new [doc](https://developers.google.com/tenor/guides/quickstart#python). It should work with the following url:

```
"https://tenor.googleapis.com/v2/search?q={}&key={}&limit=1"
```

I am far from an expert so as always I would advise to read the doc carefully.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, that was it, i was reading the old docs. Thanks a lot, changing that and the media key to media_formats worked for me :)